# GenerationValue dont work in one to one relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

i have 2 tables: userapp and owner, userapp have username as id. the relationship between both tables are one to one, and owner pk is the pk of userapp, i map this relationship like this:

UserApp entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class UserApp{

    @Id
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String role;
```

Owner Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Owner extends UserApp{

    @Column(unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue
    private int personId;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String address;
    @Column
    private String neighborhood;

    public Owner(String username, String password, String email, String name, String address, String neighborhood) {
        super(username, password, email, "owner");
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.neighborhood = neighborhood;
    }
```

i am using postgresql and when i see the tables, they are correctly created, when i create a owner  is persisted correctly too, the problem is the personId column, that for some reason the `@GeneratedValue` dont works, i mean, when i try to create other owner, i have and error that says the key personId already exits. and indeed, hibernate still create the person Id with value 0 to all new owners, i tried with all GenerationType and still have the problem

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you [map a one-to-one in JPA](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one).
What you did is [mapping inheritance](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance), that's something different.

I think the mapping you are looking for is this one:

```
@Entity
public class UserApp {

    @Id
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String role;
}

@Entity
public class Owner {

    @Id
    private int personId;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    UserApp userApp;

    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String address;
    @Column
    private String neighborhood;
}
```

Check the mapping [for one-to-one associations with `@MapsId`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived) on the Hibernate ORM documentation for more details.